# Taxi fare calculator based on distance and time in a threshold

Tags: javascript

I would like to create a taxi fare calculator which will take as params in a threshold the following:

```
const threshold = [
  {
    id: 1,
    ord: 1,
    step_distance: 100,
    step_time: 120,
    step_price: 5,
    threshold: 100,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    ord: 2,
    step_distance: 100,
    step_time: 120,
    step_price: 0.3,
    threshold: 10000,
  },
];
```

When the ride starts it will take `ord`: 1 and for every second that is elapsed or new value for distance received it will run a loop to check which of `step_distance` or `step_time` has been reached. Then it calculates how many steps are available based on `threshold / step_distance`. For example in first threshold there is only one step and in second are 100. Once in step one the time reached 120s or 100m it will add $5 for the `fare_price`, will reset the timer to 0 and will move second threshold. Here every time 100m is reached or 120s the loop will run for 100 times adding to `fare_price`, $0.3 for each step .

The way I've done it is working but I would like to know if there is a better version achieving this.

```
const [initialTime, setInitialTime] = useState(new Date());
  const [totalTime, setTotalTime] = useState(0);
  const [currentOrd, setCurrentOrd] = useState(1);
  const [currentStep, setCurrentStep] = useState(0);
  const [currentPrice, setPrice] = useState(0);
  const [routeTime, setRouteTime] = useState(0);

  const { distance, time, currentTimeAndDate } = useTracking(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const currentDistance = distance * 100;
    const diff = Math.round(
      moment.duration(moment().diff(initialTime)).asSeconds()
    );
    const totalTime = Math.round(
      moment.duration(moment().diff(currentTimeAndDate)).asSeconds()
    );
    setRouteTime(diff);
    setTotalTime(totalTime);
    if (diff || currentDistance) {
      track(currentDistance, diff);
    }
    return () => {
      null;
    };
  }, [distance, time, currentTimeAndDate]);

  const track = (distance, time) => {
    const item = threshold.filter((item) => item.ord === currentOrd);

    if (item[0].ord === currentOrd) {
      const stepDistance = item[0].step_distance;
      const stepTime = item[0].step_time;
      const price = item[0].step_price;
      const thresholdDistance = item[0].threshold;

      // IF AVAILABLE JUST RUN
      if (distance >= stepDistance * currentStep || time >= stepTime) {
        if (thresholdDistance / stepDistance === currentStep) {
          console.log("IS MAXIMUM AVAILABLE");
        } else {
          setPrice(currentPrice + price);
          const currentOrder = currentStep + 1;
          setCurrentStep(currentOrder);
        }
        setInitialTime(new Date());
        if (thresholdDistance / stepDistance - currentStep <= 0) {
          const currentOrder = currentOrd + 1;
          setCurrentOrd(currentOrder);
          setCurrentStep(1);
        }
      } else {
        console.log("Current Distance:", distance);
        console.log("Current Time:", routeTime);
      }
    }
  };
```

Comment: Didn't quite get the formula understand. To my understanding to the question: If distance reach 100, but time less than 120. We should add 5 to price, reset distance and time to 0, switch to 2nd threshold. If distance less than 100, but time reach 120. We should add 5 to price, reset time, keep distance, and continue use 1st threshold. Is this correct?

Comment: @tsh actually not. If distance reach 100 but time less than 120 or we reach time 120 while distance is less than 100 we add 5. Then we reset time and move to next threshold. Now if we reach 100 but time less than 120 or we reach 120 and distance less than 100 we add 0.3 and reset time then move to next step if available. In second threshold we have `thresholdDistance / stepDistance = 100 steps` so it will run second step for 100 times